# Event logs saved on network share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, windows-event-log

I'm currently working on a project and having problems with saving event logs where i specify them.

My problem is i want to have them saved on our file-server in a specified folder, however they wont save changes there and keeps using its already existing file, so far I've changes the log path to \FS\Domain\Logs[name of log], made the folder shared for administrators and even tried giving everyone access to the folder, however none of these are working

I have access to the file share with read/write privileges and have created the path and files manually

I would like to know if what I'm trying is even possible or what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

The better solution to trying to save your event logs to an SMB path (which, as you've seen, won't work) is to build a central log server and [set up event forwarding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's quite sensible that you can't save you main log file on a network share.
If you were able to do so, how would the system be able to write events when you don't have network or before the drivers were loaded?

What you can do is limit the size of the event log and set that the old events will be retained on a different file on that network share.

Answer (score 0):

the event log will always have be on a local disk for the simple reason that windows can boot and function without access to a network. What would it do with its logs in this case?

Instead of trying to get windows to write the events to an external log, look at exporting the logs. There are loads of tools to do this.